# How translate this code from sql to Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I need help with this code from sql to Hibernate, please I hope you help me with this work...

**`SELECT x(coordenadas) as latitud, y(coordenadas) as longitud  FROM datos;`**

I'm a new user in this page :-(

I have two tables called datos and dispositivo, I'm using hibernate from Netbeans for get registers of the table called datos, but the problem is that I dont know how convert this sentence. because my table contains a register with a type data "geometry properties functions" called "coordenadas". GeomFromText("Point(18.30 -99)"). I need get the register of this table as Latitud and Longitud in a list. Help me please :(. I sorry for my English, I'm learning.

I had a table with these registers datos,fecha,dirLat,dirLong,Latitud,Longitud,altura and I take the registers with this method...

```
package Modelo;

import com.conf.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import com.hibernate.Datos;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class FuncionesHibernate {
    public List<Datos> Tabla_Datos(){
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        List<Datos> lista = (List<Datos>)s.createQuery("From Datos").list();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        return lista;
    }
}
```

then with this code from a Servlet, I got Latitud and Longitud...

```
FuncionesHibernate funcionesHibernate = new FuncionesHibernate();
 List<Datos> lista = funcionesHibernate.Tabla_Datos();

for(Datos d : lista){
latitud=d.getLatitud();
longitud=d.getLongitud();
}
```

The problem is that the tables was updated, and the registers that contained Latitud and Longitud changed to`coordenadas` geometry. Well now I need insert registers for this new way in the console for mySql.

```
insert into datos values(1,1,"2013-02-02","14:00:00",GeomFromText("Point(18.30 -99)"),20);
```

and now my method called 'FuncionesHibernate ' can't working.

There isn't another way for 'coordenadas' registers get with the new table? What's the new query for Hibernate??

for this razon I need translate this query to query for Hibernate..

```
SELECT x(coordenadas) as latitud, y(coordenadas) as longitud  FROM datos;
```

Comment: describe your question in detail try to put code of your pojo. and what you have tried and what are the expected result you are looking for

Comment: I have two tables called datos and dispositivo,  I'm using hibernate from Netbeans for get registers of the table called datos, but the problem is that I dont know how convert this sentence. because my table contains a register with a type data "geometry properties functions" called "coordenadas". GeomFromText("Point(18.30 -99)").
I need get the register of this table as Latitud and Longitud in a list. Help me please :(. I sorry for my English, I'm learning.

Comment: You can write hql with the help of properties of your pojos. but i am still not clear you want to write query based on your pojos properties or you want to call a function of database.

Comment: Ok now i get your question you want to set a property as a output of a function of database. coordenadas will be initialize by the output of a function call named GeomFromText which take two input. Hmmm let me think are prepare solution for you.

Comment: Body thanks a lot, but you converted the query incorrect... This is the query that I need translate to Hibernate in a list... SELECT x(coordenadas) as latitud, y(coordenadas) as longitud FROM datos;

Answer (score 0):

Functions are transferred from HQL to the underlying SQL, so you can probably use pretty much the same query (just specify the correct entity name)

Another option is to use a [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/query_native.html).

Comment: There isn't another way for  'coordenadas'  registers get with the new table? What's the new query for Hibernate??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest go with native query: try below code

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
String sql = "insert into datos values(1,1,"2013-02-02","14:00:00",GeomFromText("Point(18.30 -99)"),20)";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.flush();
```

If this code works fine then replace hard-coded values with dynamic values.

**Edit:**

Add **hibernate-spatial-mysql-*.jar** in your class path and try below code.

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;


Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(52.5, 13.3);
Point point = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(coord);
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM datos WHERE WITHIN(:location, polygon) = true", Datos.class);
query.setParameter("location", point);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Body thanks a lot, but you converted the query incorrect...

This is the query that I need translate to Hibernate in a list...

SELECT x(coordenadas) as latitud, y(coordenadas) as longitud  FROM datos;

Comment: So this code is working jajajjajaja!!! but I need the other query!! help me please Real!

Comment: Please paste all you COLUMNS and currospinding POJOS properties?

Comment: Ok no need to do special just change your pojos mapping accordingly.@Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
    @Column(name = "the_geom", nullable = true)
    private Geometry geom;

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 04-feb-2013 9:45:12 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.Datos" table="datos" catalog="gps">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="dispositivo" class="com.hibernate.Dispositivo" fetch="select">

Comment: <column name="id_dispositivo" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="fecha" type="date">
            <column name="fecha" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="hora" type="time">
            <column name="hora" length="8" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="coordenadas" type="binary">
            <column name="coordenadas" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="altura" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="altura" precision="6" />
        </property>
    </class>

Comment: modified answer to meet your requirement.

Comment: I've a error in this sentence ... Query query = session.createQuery("FROM datos WHERE WITHIN(:location, polygon) = true", Datos.class); says "required: String found: String,Class"... I need find the correct JAR